# Tableau: Unable to import AD users to tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to import 2 active AD users to tableau. 
When I click on "Import Users", it keeps spinning for a long time and then the error message appears that "Error while importing users"
Can someone please help with this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Error Message: An unexpected error occurred while processing your request. Try again.

Comment: Look in the Tableau Server log files. You should see more detailed messages there.